# Android detect USB mount and unmount from device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to detect when a USB is mounted or unmounted from my device.

I have tried using `Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED` in the broadcast receiver but it's not working.

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "mounted usb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Un-mounted usb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nik, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help people give you advice if you can be more specific about what's going wrong and possibly show us some code that you've tried. For example, you mention `Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED` not working - how about showing us that block of code and the error it produces?

Comment: Why it's not working? Can you post the log? And the logcat

Comment: This my code in the broadcast receiver onreceive method. i have also registered receiver in my activity.                                                 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED)){

             Toast.makeText(context, "mounted usb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     } 
        else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED))
{
    
    Toast.makeText(context, "Un-mounted usb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
   }

Comment: @Nik It would be more helpful to edit the code into your original question - I've taken care of this for you, but you may want to check that the linebreaks and indents are correct as I'm not familiar with Java.